# assembly x86 command line arguments

Tags: assembly, x86, command-line-arguments, masm

I am trying to write a simple program in x86 (using MASM to compile).
It's purpose is to write command line arguments to output (each in a new line).
Here's what I came up with so far:

```
data1 segment
   input db 40 dup (?)   ;input                   
data1 ends


code1   segment

START:                           
   mov ax,seg input
   mov ds,ax
   mov dx,offset input
   mov di, dx 

   mov si, 82h
   mov cl,es:[80h]    


word:   
      mov al,es:[si]
      mov ds:[di],al   
      inc si   
      inc di   

      cmp al,0Dh   ;out of arguments? (if YES goto finish)
      jz finish

      cmp al,20h   ;end of word? (if NO goto word)
      jnz word

   mov al, '$'  ;line terminate
   mov ds:[di], al

   mov ah,09h      ;write string
   int 21h 

   xor di,di    ;prepare registry for new word

   call new_line


   loop word

finish: 


   mov al, '$'
   mov ds:[di], al

   mov ah,09h      ;write last argument
   int 21h  


   mov ax,4ch   ;end program
   int 21h


new_line:
   push ax
   push bp
   mov ax,0e0ah ;ah=0e-write char,al=0a-go to new line
   int 10h
   mov al,13     ;carriage return
   int 10h 
   pop bp
   pop ax
ret

code1 ends  
end START
```

It seems to work fine when tested under emu8086 but after compiling with MASM it gives the correct results only in 10% of executions.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your program does not have a stack segment and doesn't have to work on the basis of just that. Your program does not terminate correctly either.

Answer (score 1):

It's been so long since I looked at any assembler...big hints rather than `here's your answer`

Are you sure ES is loaded with the appropriate segment, since you aren't initialising it?

Note that by loading CL with the contents of 80H, you sre setting CL to the LENGTH of the command line.

When you loop back to WORD (not a good name for a label, btw - since it's a keyword) you are transferring the next byte. All very well and good - but you are NOT decrementing CL, the count of characters in the command line. You should be jumping to the LOOP instruction which decrements CX and returns to the target label if 0 is not reached.

You've very carefully (and correctly) saved BP and AX before executing the `INT 10h` Is saving these two registers sufficient? Perhaps other registers are modified also...

Similarly, the `INT 21H` - are there any registers that may be changed by the execution of the routine behind this interrupt? If so, you should `PUSH` them first and `POP` them back after the routine finishes.

Be very caeful about relying on the CR=0DH=13 to end the line. This will be missing if the available space for arguments is COMPLETELY filled. The character count in CL is more important. Provided you correctly decrement CL by using the `LOOP` instruction, you won'tencounter the CR (IIRC) as it doesn't form part of the count. That assumes, of course, that `CX` is not changed by all of the folderol checking for a space or **writing out the line**...

Oh, btw - conventionally, a new line is `CR`,`LF` or 0DH,0AH - in that order. On mechanical terminals, this was quite literally moving the printhead back to the left-hand side, then scrolling the paper up by a line. The printheads were quite solid and gathered a large amount of momentum when they were returned against a spring-loaded stop. The consequence was that they'd often bounce and the beginning characters of the next line would be sprayed over the first few columns on the printout as the printhead settled, each new line inexorably jarring the mechanics more and more out of adjustment. In fact, it was not unusual to have a newline be CR LF CR, just to allow the mechanics time to settle.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start copying the argument strings you do:

```
mov dx,offset input
mov di, dx
```

But if there are more than one argument you do this after the first argument has been printed:

```
xor di,di    ;prepare registry for new word
```

That should probably have been `mov di, dx` unless you're absolutely, positively, 100% certain that the offset of `input` always will be 0.