# Print command line arguments assembly x86

Tags: assembly, printing, x86, arguments, nasm

I am trying to print args in the terminal, but I still was not able to do that. I even found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808379/assembly-x86-command-line-arguments) on how to do that, but it didn't work to me.

I tried running this code to print the first argument, but unfortunately no success:

```
section .text
        global main

main:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, [ebp + 8]
        mov edx, 10
        int 0x80

        mov eax, 1
        xor ebx, ebx
        int 0x80
```

How can I print all the arguments?

Comment: Your function doesn't set EBP so it just points somewhere random.  If you fixed that by setting it up as a frame pointer, `[ebp+8]` would be `argv` with type `char **`, not `argv[0]` or `argv[1]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes can you provide me an example of code of how can I do that? I'm pretty noob on that, that would be awesome.

Comment: The Q&A you linked ([assembly x86 command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15808379)) is 16-bit DOS code with MASM syntax.  You're writing 32-bit Linux code with NASM.  So of course it didn't work; you need to look for tutorials / guides for the platform you're using.

Comment: [What exactly is the base pointer and stack pointer? To what do they point?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395591) is one of the hits from `site:stackoverflow.com ebp frame pointer`

Comment: [Printing Commandline Arguments x86 Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54282001) is basically a duplicate, even though the (mostly) working code answer is in the *question*.